# GeoTrust SSL certificate on Android not trusted

Tags: android, ssl

I have bought Extended Validation SSL certificate from GeoTrust and configured it to get A ranking on:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=goout.cz

However on my Android device in Chrome I am getting "Certificate not Trusted". What might be the problem? I suppose I have configured everything correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install appropriate intermediary certificates.

[Quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=geotrust+certificate+android) brings up following pages:

https://support.servertastic.com/rapidssl-and-geotrust-certificate-not-trusted-on-mobile-device/

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?958488-GeoTrust-SSL-Certificate-for-Android-devices